# Visual Studio Code auto sftp generated files like .min.css

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, less, sftp, minify

I have a problem with Visual Studio Code. I am using less files so added extensions to auto generate .css and other to make .min.css files. The problem is "ftp-simple" and "sftp" extensions which are used to auto send files to my server after saving do not send .css or min.css. Maybe someone has the same problem and knows solutions?

if i save my css file it works - send to serv. But wanna make it automaticly after save less

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, what are the IDs and version of the extensions you are using? What are the relevant options in your workspace and user settings for those extensions?

Answer (score 0):

after long searching I found that in an extension calles "SFTP" by Natizyskunk You can add a watch which would upload generated files on save.
So now I must only save .less and have .css and .css.map on my serv.

sftp.json code:

```
{
    "name": "your_name",
    "host": "your_host",
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "port": 21,
    "username": "your_username",
    "password": "your_password",
    "remotePath": "/",
    "uploadOnSave": true,
    "watcher": {
        "files": "**/*.{jss,css,css.map,.min.css,.min.js}",
        "autoUpload": true,
        "autoDelete": false
    },
    "useTempFile": false,
    "openSsh": false
}
```